# How to protect a sqlite3 database made with python of "outside" editing

Tags: python, sqlite, data-protection

First of all sorry for my bad english, is not my native lenguage.

So I have a python (2.7) program that READ, DELETE, and INSERT data into a sqlite3 database. (The program is done and works fine).

My new problem is that I don't want that the database can be edited with, for example, "SQLite Data Browser". I only want that the database can be edited (DELETE and INSERT) through my python program. ¿Is that possible?

Working on linux (Raspbian).
Python 2.7.
The code is to large and I don't think is necesary either.

thanks in advance !

Comment: Not really, no. Why do you think you need this?

Comment: Well, if you _really_ don't want anyone to edit this database, you can encrypt it, so that nobody even has any idea what it is. Then, your Python code can decrypt it easily, provided that it has the key and you keep the key somewhere secure, so that no one can do the decryption.

Comment: I need to do this because the program is going to be used by other people. So I need to be sure that the data has not been modified by those people and is modified just by the program.

Comment: What prevents those people from modifying your Python program?

Comment: I'm working on that to (they are not programmer or super clever people), I was thinking on compile my program from .py to .pyc.

Answer (score 0):

Your English is fine.

Suppose it were possible. That would mean only your program is able to authenticate with the database. Which means it gets credentials from somewhere or stores them somewhere..

Your code lives on a Raspberry PI. If you can touch the Raspberry PI, you can just pull the SD card and access the database and the code.

Comment: It doesn't matter if someone can get the info from the raspberry and edit it on another environment. What is important, for me atleast, Is the security of knowing that the information stored in the database (Raspberry) has not been modified.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for something like this
But I think of two solutions.

1. Encryption and decryption from the program.
2. Every time you edit the database from within python, you generate a checksum and store that checksum in the database, if someone modified the database outside the program the checksum will be changed so you can know that the database has been modified from outside the program.

As you have said they are not clever people so they will not generate a checksum and change your checksum.

If they can do it, store your checksum online and fetch it every time you load your program.